# Open a new activity for each item clicked from GridView

Tags: gridview, android-intent, android-activity

In this program a list is shown as a grid. When i click on the list, the selected item will open a new activity. But it's not working properly. Only showing the GridItem & Textviewing the clicked item. Clicking not openning a new activity/intent

this is what i have...

The GridViewDemo.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GridViewDemo extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    TextView selection;
String[] items = { "One", "Two", "Three };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

            //Intent i = new Intent(this, One.class) something will declare here

    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            items );

    gv.setAdapter(aa);
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

//i want to start a new intent here accordong to the possition (One, two, Three.class)
//i don't need the textview
    selection.setText(items[position]);

    }

}
```

## This will help

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {     
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

try {
Class classe = Class.forName("com.google.GridViewDemo." + items[position]);
Intent i = new Intent(this, classe);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Implement onItemClickListener to your activity.

2) Than add Unimplemented Methods.

3) in onItemClick()  Method you will get somethong like this:

```
 @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DestinationActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {               
                Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this, GalleryView.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```